# How to create a (Polymorphism) collection/list/array of a class where each one may have some different properties

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, polymorphism, abstract

If i wanted to create a **Car Engine Design** for a game i will do the following:

**The Base class:**

```
public class EngineParts {
        public string name;
        public int ID; 
        public GameObject Mesh; 
        public Vector3 Position; 
        public Quaternion Rotation; 
        public string Description;
        public float new_value; // the brand new price of it
}
```

**Then i would have the classes that inherits from it:**

```
public class Rods : EngineParts
    {    
    }

public class Pistons : EngineParts
    {
        public float Size=51;
        public float Compression=51;
    }

public class Turbo : EngineParts
    {
        public float maxboostpressure;
        public float minboostpressure;
        public float MaxOperatingRPM;
        public float MinOperatingRPM;
        public float AirToEngineRatio;
        public float wasteGatePressure;
    }
```

The importing thing here is that all car parts share some common values that are in the **Base** class those values are name, ID, Mesh, Position, Rotation.. etc

They also have other values that are more specific for the part itself, like for instance the Turbo has *maxboostpressure*  which determines the maximum pressure of boost the turbo can handle.

Now in the actual game I need to be able to make the use of the parts as one collection

```
public EngineParts[] Part = new EngineParts[3];

Part[0] = new Rods();
Part[1] = new Pistons();
Part[2] = new Turbo();
```

I can therefore loop through all parts when needed since they are all of type **EngineParts**.

But when trying to assign a value to max *maxboostpressure*, i am unable to do that.

```
   //Note: Part[1] here is pistons
    Part[1].name = "SportPiston"; // this will work since it is type of EngineParts
    Part[1].maxboostpressure = 5.0; // this will not work
```

and that is due to that it is of type *EngineParts*

I can however say:

```
Rods rd = new Rods();
Pistons pt = new Pistons();
Turbo tb = new Turbo();

pt.name = 5; // this will work
pt.maxboostpressure = 5; // this will work
```

Now they do share the same DAta from the Base class, but i cant put the Rods, Pistons, Turbo in one collection to loop through or pass them in a function that works on all of them.

So 
**Question Here is** 
How can i best do this?
1- Have all the parts of the engine in one collection/List
2- Be able to have extra data stored on each individual type of part as well with minimum coding.

I have been reading about 
*Abstract Classes, Overloading, Polymorphism, and INHERITANCE* to solve this but still there is something that i must miss understand, so if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be highly appreciated.

**Thank you in Advance**

Comment: unfortunately compiler cannot do this for you because all values are boxed to base class and compiler cannot automatically  unbox it with looking on indexes of array. this should be done in runtime like given answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a cast like this:

```
Piston p = Part[1] as Piston;
```

p will be null if Part[1] isn't a Piston.

Then continue with

```
if(p!=null)
    doSomethingHere;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much for your kind answer.

Comment: @AliT, Hi, I'm glad to read, that this could help you! As you are new to SO, please be aware, that the professionals giving answers here, are hungry for reputation points. It would be very kind of you to vote helpful answers up and - if an answer helped you to solve your problem - you should mark it as the accepted answer, This will show to others, that this question is solved. Thx!

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for the help, i marked your answer as accepted, and voted it up, thanks for pointing me to that, what are reputation points good for tho?

Comment: makes you feel happy believe me xD @AliT

Comment: @AliT, I'm here for 3 months and kind of addicted ;-)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Hi, voted yours up to make you happy ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to separate your array into parts of subclasses. Using linq

```
EngineParts[] Part = new EngineParts[3];

Part[0] = new Rods();
Part[1] = new Pistons();
Part[2] = new Turbo();

Rods[] rods = Part.Where(x => x is Rods).Cast<Rods>().ToArray();
Pistons[] position = Part.Where(x => x is Pistons).Cast<Pistons>().ToArray();
Turbo[] turbo = Part.Where(x => x is Turbo).Cast<Turbo>().ToArray();

Turbo[0].name = "SportPiston"; 
Turbo[0].maxboostpressure = 5.0;
```

You will have 3 seperate arrays with known type. now you can work with them individually.

Notice that indexes are no more like before. So if you dont want this why not already create separate arrays for them? ;)

Answer (score 2):

The question is, how do you know that the 3rd item in the list is a specific sub-class?

You currently know because you are specifically assigning it a location in the array, however you should approach this as at any time, any sub-class could be in any position in the array.

With that in mind you need to check the type of the array item, and then cast it before you can work on it.

```
if(Part[1] is Turbo)
{
   ((Turbo)Part[1]).maxboostpressure = 5;
}
```

There are a few ways you can test the type:

`typeof` takes a type name (which you specify at compile time).

`GetType` gets the runtime type of an instance.

`is` returns true if an instance is in the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "is" and "as" operators.

```
var list = new List<EngineParts>();

// add some parts to the list here...

foreach(var part in list) {
  if(part is Turbo) {
    (part as Turbo).maxboostpressure = 123;
  }
}
```

Comment: really there is no need to check type twice. use `as` once and check if its null or not. note that here `is` and `as` will both check type individually.

Answer (score 1):

no copies, etc...

```
var lst = new List<EngineParts>(); //fill it
foreach(var itm in lst.Where(x => x is Piston).Cast<Piston>())
{
    itm.maxboostpressure = 42;
}
```